# Flutter+Retrofit / How to correctly parse json API of type <Map>?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, retrofit

Help me understand why I can't parse such a simple API using Retrofit?

If I parse the same API content in a [] - everything works fine.

Repo: https://github.com/serhv1/rtf_app
API: https://run.mocky.io/v3/dfb63938-dbb3-45d6-b66c-46b5025b5f0a

DEBUG CONSOLE:

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#d7b62):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List'

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder
home.dart:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Home._body.
home.dart:29

Tried using convert package functions with no success